# Handling Put requests on Java side

Tags: java, put

I have a dynamic web project where in I use apache cxf and HTTP. Now I've worked with POST and GET requests before.

On the java side, I'd use annotation `@GET/@POST` etc and from the UI I can make requests to it.

I was just reading about the `PUT` request and I am not able to place it just well in the above scenario. As much as I understand, PUT is used to add data or upload data. Now, what I don't understand is that

1. How is PUT handled on java side. Can I please have an example here (link).
2. Why use PUT? Even if I want to add some info, or upload, I can use POST for the same and then add it to my data source.

Comment: PUT is used to edit/update an existing resource. It is the U in the CRUD model. How it is handled server side is entirely up to you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904001/why-use-http-put-and-delete-methods-instead-of-post

Comment: @TimCastelijns PUT also plays the role of C in CRUD when the resource does not exist yet (in theory)

Comment: That is true :-) forgot to mention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A HTTP PUT is handled by a method that is annotated with [`@PUT`](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/PUT.html).

```
@PUT
@Path("/foo/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response putAFoo(@PathParam("id") int theId, Foo theFoo) {
  // Save theFoo which has theId or do what you want with it.
  if (fooWasCreated) {
    return Response.created("/foo/" + theId).build();
  } else {
    return Response.ok().build();
  }
}
```

Why use PUT? Usually PUT is used to change the server side state of a known resource. If you can address a resource by the comple URI, you can use this URI to GET a representation of it. You can also PUT to this URL with a *new* representation of the resource.

PUT is also used to create a new resource if the ID is controlled by the server. A request

```
PUT /foo/123
```

can be used to

1. overwrite `/foo/123` or
2. create `/foo/123`.

That is different from POST which is usually requested on the collection resource.

```
POST /foo/
```

with the representation of a new resource would cause the server to assign an ID to the new resource. The server would then return a response like this:

```
201 Created
Location: /foo/456
```

Answer (score 2):

1. There is a `@PUT` example on the [Apache CXF http-binding page](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/http-binding.html).
2. Why use PUT? Well, in a RESTful application, you would want for example to implement an add/edit functionality for an entity, say, `MyEntity`.

   Now, the add would go on a link like: `/myApplication/myEntity` on the `POST` method, while the edit would go on `/myApplication/myEntity/id`, but on `PUT`. The `GET` request would also go on the previous link `/myApplication/myEntity/id`, and same goes for `DELETE`.

   You are basically providing CRUD operation support for `MyEntity` in a standard, straightforward way. Of course, you could do the `PUT` and `DELETE` operations through a `POST`, and that would also work.

   You can read more on RESTful webservices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming), and more on [PUT vs POST here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest).