# Using DELETE or PUT to delete a foreign key in a database?

Tags: restful-url, rest

We are currently creating a web app that mimics how flickr works as a project.

In this app, we have a galleries and photos.

In each gallery, we store the photo ids in an array.

`gallery.photos = [ photoId1, photoId2, photoId3 ]`

If we want to delete a photo from the gallery, however the photo stays on the database and can be accessed if you go to the user's profile but not from the gallery.

so if we do `DELETE url/gallery/photos/photoId3` then `GET url/gallery/photos/photoId3`, it would return an `Error 404`.

There's an argument currently happening on whether we should use `DELETE` or `PUT`.

some say `DELETE` as we are deleting things and photo isn't accessible from that url.

others say `PUT` as we are just editing the list of photo ids.

So, my question is, is there a common convention when it comes to this problem ?

Comment: If you are replacing *the array* with a new one, PUT. If you are deleting *an item* from the array, DELETE. The snippet you show is deleting an item.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POST vs PUT vs DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905762/post-vs-put-vs-delete)

Comment: No, I get that we use `GET`, `PUT` and so on to follow the protocol and we can have same urls with different method to represent different things, but it all comes down to the argument that we aren't really deleting the photo, we are deleting the reference for it from the gallery.

Comment: However the photo is still not accessible from the same url `GET /gallery/photos/photoId3`.

Comment: Surely the photo shouldn't be at /gallery/photos/photoId3 - it should be at /photos/photoId3 ?

Comment: My bad it should've been `/gallery/galleryId/photos/photoId3` to represent that we want the photo that has id of `photoId3` from that gallery that has an id of `galleyId`

Comment: So If I remove the photo from the gallery, `GET /gallery/galleryId/photos/photoId3` would return an `Error 404` as photo isn't in **that** gallery, however `GET /photos/photoId3` would still return the photo assuming you have the correct permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a common convention when it comes to this problem ?

The important thing to recognize is that DELETE and PUT are of the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s) domain.

We use the standard methods in standard ways so that general purpose components can understand what the messages mean and do intelligent things.

If the *semantics* of the request are "the target uri should answer GET requests with a 404", then DELETE is appropriate.  The underlying details of how your implementation achieves this are irrelevant.

Note that the definition of [DELETE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5) is pretty explicit about the limits of the semantics

> If the target resource has one or more current representations, they might or might not be destroyed by the origin server, and the associated storage might or might not be reclaimed, depending entirely on the nature of the resource and its implementation by the origin server (which are beyond the scope of this specification).

---

Where things get really messy: HTTP gives us agreement on the meaning of the semantics of messages, but does not restrict implementations.  In particular, it is perfectly valid that a DELETE of one resource would also change the representation of some other resource, or vice versa.

Imagine, if you will, that the gallery is a web page (/gallery/1/photos/webpage.html), with links to images, including a link to /gallery/1/photos/3.

```
DELETE  /gallery/1/photos/3
```

That removes the association between the URI and the image data, but it doesn't (necessarily) change the web page, so you get a broken link.

```
PUT /gallery/1/photos/webpage.html
```

That takes the link out of the web page, but of course the image can still be accessed directly via its URI.

(Note: if your profile was using the same URI for the image as your gallery, then this is more likely to be the model you want to use.  We take the link out of this web page, but not out of profile.html.  DELETE would produce 404's for ALL web pages that link to the picture).

If you want *both* - when the DELETE happens, the web page should be updated automatically, or vice versa - you can do that within your implementation (side effects are allowed).  BUT... general purpose components will not necessarily know that both things have happened.  For example, a general purpose cache isn't going to know that the webpage changed when you DELETE the image.  And it won't know that you removed the image when you edit the web page.

Which is to say, we don't have a standard way to include in the HTTP response metadata that describes the *other* resources that have been changed by a request.

You can, of course, include that information in the response so that a *bespoke* component can do intelligent things.

```
DELETE /gallery/1/photos/photoId3

200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

Deleted: /gallery/1/photos/photoId3
Changed: /gallery/1/photos/webpage.html
```

---

> GET /gallery/galleryId/photos/photoId3 would return an Error 404 as photo isn't in that gallery, however GET /photos/photoId3 would still return the photo assuming you have the correct permissions

The good news: general purpose components don't know that there is any relationship between `/gallery/galleryId/photos/photoId3` and `/photos/photoId3`.  Again, the fact that they share information under the covers is an implementation detail hidden behind the HTTP facade.