# Why is Delete/put request important?

Tags: php, laravel, w3c

I am new to laravel. I made an website to do simple CRUD operation. In my web.php I used route::post() to delete a data. It worked perfectly.

Later I learned that, there is a delete method in laravel. Why should I use delete method when post works perfectly?

Comment: You asked duplicate question look here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904001/why-use-http-put-and-delete-methods-instead-of-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904001/why-use-http-put-and-delete-methods-instead-of-post)

Comment: @sharif854 in the future, please vote to close the question as a duplicate, instead of editing the question, which should be reserved to make needed improvements.

Comment: HEAD, DELETE, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, and GET request methods have specific [HTTP 1.1 standards](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), that correspond to the acceptable responses each should serve.

Answer (score 0):

`Post` method is laravel is a simple post request that form does while submitting, but `Delete` method in laravel specify the type of method being used while posting data, so when you are using `Delete` method then your form must have `Delete` input field which specifies the type of action your form is doing on submit with post request. But with simple `Post` method you don't need any `post` field it's just a post request with data. for more reference check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-prefixes