# Why use PUT when POST is doing the same? Specifically in Laravel

Tags: rest, api, post, put

Well I know about the idompotence of HTTP methods. I also know about what PUT and POST are specifically used for in REST API. But the question is why use PUT when POST is doing the same.

Take the example of Laravel (PHP Framework), In Laravel we fake POST to be used as PUT method to update the data e.g changing a project name. The question is we can do the same operation i.e updating the project name using POST method without Faking it as PUT then why use PUT?

Comment: Duplicate question, here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/904013/8463337

Comment: POST shoud'nt be idempotent, PUT should be, see here: https://restfulapi.net/rest-put-vs-post/

Answer (score 0):

The http call `PUT /products/{id}` is *idempotent*, that is: each subsequent identical call made the same modifications and can be called many times with the same identical result.

The http call `POST /products` is **NOT** *idempotent*, that is, each subsequent identical call should create a new child of the product resource.

**PUT** is used to UPDATE existing resources, **POST** is used to CREATE new ones.

Note that, if you want to be **REST** compliant (as Laravel try to do) you shoud make idempotent **GET**, **PUT**, **DELETE**, **HEAD**, **OPTIONS** and **TRACE** HTTP methods but not the **POST** method.

Laravel let you faking **PUT** method calls in a HTML form using a `_method` parameter because you can't make **PUT** request with a browser. 
But, to follow **REST** principles, Laravel is able to respond to fake **PUT** call (from the browser) but also to real PUT method coming from others programs with the same route.

Comment: please, for other's reference, accept the answer if you find it's correct.