# POST or DEL to delete an item

Tags: restful-url

I saw some websites design the API by using `POST` to delete an item, some use `DELETE` with parameters to delete the item. which one is more appropriate?

**POST**

```
https://xxx/item_delete
```

**request body**

```
item: "ABC"
matured: "True"
```

or
**DELETE**

```
https://xxx/item_delete/ABC
```

Comment: To be more linguistically, use `DELETE`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904001/why-use-http-put-and-delete-methods-instead-of-post